# delete file from /etc/profile.d directory

Tags: 12.04, scripts

I have made a small script and placed it in a file inside /etc/profile.d directory. Since then, I can not login in ubuntu 12.04, nor in terminal as the normal user. I can only login as root from recovery mode.

When I login as root, I try to delete the file but reaction is

> can not remove file x...  read only file system.

I also try to change it in root with nano (put comments everywhere), but I can not save it. Is there any way to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remount the Filesystem when you are in the recovery mode.

`mount -o remount,rw /`

This will remount the root-Filesystem "read-write" and you can proceed to change what you have to change.